# ASP.Net MVC 3 - Order in HandleError attribute seems to work backwards?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, handleerror

**Problem**: When I use the `Order` property of the `HandleError` attribute, the *highest* order number gets applied first, as opposed to the lowest first.

**Details**

I want to set up my controller to handle exceptions in this way:

- if the type of the exception is `CustomException`, use the "CustomError" view.
- otherwise, use the default "Error" view.

Using the default MVC project template, I've done the following:

- Removed the `HandleErrorAttribute` from the global filters.
- Turned Custom Errors on in the `web.config`.

Then I add these attributes to the `HomeController` class:

```
[HandleError(ExceptionType = typeof(Exception), View = "Error")]
[HandleError(ExceptionType = typeof(CustomException), View = "CustomError")]
```

And this works fine - if a `CustomException` is thrown, the "CustomError" view is shown; if an `Exception` is thrown, the "Error" view is shown.

However, I thought the `Order` property on the `HandleError` attribute would make things more explicit. From the [MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.handleerrorattribute%28v=VS.98%29.aspx):

> The greater the integer value is, the lower the priority of the filter
>   is.

From this, I would have thought that the following code would cause the "Error" view to be shown in all circumstances:

```
[HandleError(Order = 1, ExceptionType = typeof(Exception), View = "Error")]
[HandleError(Order = 2, ExceptionType = typeof(CustomException), View = "CustomError")]
```

But this is not the case; this causes the same behaviour as when the `Order` property was not specified. If I swap the Orders around, ***this*** causes the "Error" view to be shown, even if a `CustomException` was thrown.

Basically, the actual order priority seems to be exactly the opposite of the documentation. Am I doing something wrong or is this a bug?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please follow this link:

http://forums.asp.net/t/1699131.aspx/1?Filter+Execution+Order+Backwards

order was changed to opposite

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for posting this question!  Believe it or not, Microsoft's [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.handleerrorattribute(v=vs.108).aspx) on this feature is still incorrect three years later.  I've submitted a [bug report](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/1024) to the ASP.NET team to get this fixed.